How to link a wallet without connecting to the app
I want to add a functionality for the users to be able to link multiple wallets to the app. I am using unified wallet adapter from jupiter. Able to open the wallet modal manually but, when I connect the wallet, it always connect to the app. I would like that, when user clicks on a link wallet button (which is a custom button to open the unidiedWallet modal manually) the user is asked to sign a transaction and a new wallet as an additional wallet is linked to the app and it does not connect to the app. I would like the previous wallet to stay connected to the app and the new wallet should just be linked and not connected (Replacing connection of previous wallet)
Here are my unifiedWallet configs
import React, { FC, useCallback, useMemo, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { UnifiedWalletProvider, WalletAdapterNetwork, useUnifiedWalletContext} from "@jup-ag/wallet-adapter";
import { PhantomWalletAdapter } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets";
import { TipLinkWalletAdapter } from "@tiplink/wallet-adapter";
import { TipLinkWalletAutoConnectV2 } from "@tiplink/wallet-adapter-react-ui";
import '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui/styles.css';
import { SolanaSignInInput } from "@solana/wallet-standard-features";
import styles from '../styles/Wallet.module.css';

type Props = {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
};

export const Wallet: FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const [isAutoConnected, setIsAutoConnected] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const wallets = useMemo(() => {
    const allwalletAdapters = {
      "PhantomWalletAdapter": PhantomWalletAdapter,
    };

    const walletAdapters = Object.keys(allwalletAdapters)
      .filter((key) => key.includes("Adapter"))
      .map((key) => (allwalletAdapters as any)[key])
      .map((WalletAdapter: any) => new WalletAdapter());

    walletAdapters.push(
      new TipLinkWalletAdapter({
        title: "TipLink Sample dApp",
        clientId: "*******",
        theme: "dark",
        walletAdapterNetwork: WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet
      })
    );

    return [...walletAdapters].filter((item) => item && item.name && item.icon);
  }, []);

  const autoSignIn = useCallback(async (wallet: any) => {
    if (!wallet.signIn) {
      return true;
    }

    try {
      // Fetch the signInInput from the backend
      const createResponse = await fetch("/apitest/test/test");
      const input: SolanaSignInInput = await createResponse.json();

      // Trigger sign-in with the wallet
      const output = await wallet.signIn(input);

      // Verify the sign-in output server-side
      const strPayload = JSON.stringify({ input, output });
      const verifyResponse = await fetch("/apitest/test", {
        method: "POST",
        body: strPayload,
      });
      const success = await verifyResponse.json();

      return success;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Auto sign-in failed:", error);
      return false;
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const tryAutoSignIn = async () => {
      const connectedWallet = wallets.find((wallet) => wallet.connected); 

      if (connectedWallet) {
        const connected = await autoSignIn(connectedWallet);
        setIsAutoConnected(connected);
      }
    };

    tryAutoSignIn();
  }, [wallets, autoSignIn]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.UnifiedWalletModal}>
      <UnifiedWalletProvider
        wallets={wallets}
        config={{
          autoConnect: isAutoConnected, // Set boolean value here
          env: "devnet",
          metadata: {
            name: "UnifiedWallet",
            description: "UnifiedWallet",
            url: "https://jup.ag",
            iconUrls: ["https://jup.ag/favicon.ico"],
          },
          walletlistExplanation: {
            href: "https://station.jup.ag/docs/additional-topics/wallet-list",
          },
          theme: "dark",
          lang: "en",
        }}
      >
        <TipLinkWalletAutoConnectV2 isReady query={searchParams!}>
          {children}
        </TipLinkWalletAutoConnectV2>
      </UnifiedWalletProvider>
    </div>
  );
};


Here is how I am opening the modal manually
import { useUnifiedWalletContext } from "@jup-ag/wallet-adapter";
const UserProfile: React.FC = () => {
   const { setShowModal } = useUnifiedWalletContext();
   const setUnifiedWalletModalVisibility = () => {
        setShowModal(true);
    }

return (
  <div>
      <button className="px-2.5 py-2 bg-[#6F6CFF] text-white border-none rounded cursor-pointer" onClick={setUnifiedWalletModalVisibility}>
        Link wallet
     </button>
  </div>
)
}

